# chef-solo with vagrant "LoadError cannot load such file -- mysql2"

Tags: vagrant, mysql2, chef-solo, vagrant-provision

Vagrant provision throws this error

> Error executing action `drop` on resource 'mysql_database[database_name]'
>
> LoadError
>
> cannot load such file -- mysql2

My code snippet which throws the error is as follows

```
mysql_database  node['mysql_database'] do
  connection mysql_connection_info
  action [:drop,:create]
end
```

My cookbook is installing mysql2 gem in the vagrant machine.

> vagrant@ubuntu-14:~$ gem list --local
>
> mysql2 (0.4.1, 0.4.0)

I couldn't figure out why is it still not able to load the mysql2 gem. Any help is appreciated.